# What is the group $K/\mathcal(O)_{P}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I try do the exercise 1.21 d (page 69) of Hartshorne's algebraic geometry, which is the following:

Let $X= \mathbb{P}^1 $, $\mathcal{O}$ its sheaf of regular functions and $\mathcal{O}_{p}$ the sheaf of regular functions of a point $p \in \mathbb{P}^1 $. Denote by $\mathcal{K}$ the constant sheaf associated to the function field $K$ of $X$. 
Show that the quotient sheaf $\mathcal{K}/\mathcal{O}$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of sheaves $\sum_{x \in X} i_{p}(I_{p})$, where $I_p$ is the group $K/\mathcal{O}_{p}$ and $i_{p}(I_{p})$ denotes the skyscraper sheaf given by $I_p$ at the point $p$

> What is meant by the group $K/\mathcal{O}_{p}$?

Since $K$ is a group (even a field), but $\mathcal{O}_{p}$ is a sheaf, I don't know how this should be understand.

Only to be sure:
The constant sheaf $\mathcal{K}$ on $X$ associated to $K$ is given by $\mathcal{K}(U)=K$ for any open $U$ of $X$. Is that correct?

Comment: (I think:) $K$ is a sheaf, namely the sheaf of meromorphic functions. $\mathcal{O}_p$ is a subsheaf of it, namely the subsheaf of meromorphic functions regular at $p$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: But how can this be interpreted as a group, which is crucial for the exercise?

Comment: $\mathcal O_p$ is just a ring. It's the direct limit of $\mathcal O(U)$ as $U$ runs over neighborhoods of $p$.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to change your $\mathcal H$'s to $\mathcal K$'s, which are Hartshorne's (and everybody else's) notation . And to answer your last question: yes, your description is  absolutely correct.

Comment: @Hoot: Yes, you're right and can write it as an answer.